# How can I choose bootstrap.yml according to db config?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, alibaba-cloud, nacos

I have two nacos bootstrap.yml which means two nacos with different ip, I want to load one of the `bootstrap.yml` according to db config.

For example, if my `loadVariable` value from db config is `A`, I want to load `bootstrap-a.yml`. How can I do that?

Here is my purpose step:

1. search data from db to decide load `bootstrap-a.yml` or `bootstrap-b.yml`
2. register the service to nacos according to bootstrap config file

Comment: Does this answer your question? [howto-change-configuration-depending-on-the-environment](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.2.0.M1/reference/html/howto-properties-and-configuration.html#howto-change-configuration-depending-on-the-environment)

Comment: @SaravanakrishnanPk,How can I load value from db and then use profile to load then? I have search most example,and all of them tell me to config the profile  like set `spring.profiles.active`.But I want to set this to my database like mysql config table.

Comment: you have a chicken and egg problem. bootstrap loads files long before database connections are made